# What are the parameters $w$ and $b$ represent in the hyperplane eqution?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

A hyperplane in $\mathbb{R}^d$ is determined by $w\in\mathbb{R}^d$ and $b\in\mathbb{R}$ in the eqution$$H=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^d:w\cdot x+b=0\}$$
How does changing $w$ and $b$ effect $H$? Or, in other words, what properties of $H$ are determined by $w$ and $b$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$w$ is the orthogonal direction to the hyperplane, and $b$ represents how far the plane is removed from the origin in that direction. More specifically, the point with position vector $- \frac{b \cdot \vec{w}}{|\vec{w}|^2}$ lies in the plane.

Changing $w$ without changing $b$ and the length of $w$ rotates the plane around the origin; changing $b$ translates it towards or away from the origin.

Comment: What does changing the length of $w$ "do" to $H$?

Comment: It also changes translates the hyperlane towards or away from the origin; however, inversely so (i.e. increasing the length of $w$ moves the plane towards the origin and decreasing its length moves it away from the origin).